# Why can't I access my local server with DHCP-assigned ip?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

Watching a tutorial, guy starts a simple http server on python and can access it from the same machine using local network ip (192.168.*.*), I did the same thing but I can only access the server from the same machine as localhost (127.0.0.1). I can access the server from another machines on the LAN with LAN ip. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try to disable your firewall.

Comment: Please describe _everything_ you did to launch the HTTP server. Also, does the last sentence mean that your HTTP server is indeed accessible from other devices on your local network?